# Selecting between paths in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool, path, selections

I have multiple paths (not intersecting), each one of them consists of two anchor points only. Imagine a path from A to B and the second one from C to D. What I want to do is to select the space ABCD. I tried using Direct Selection Tool, but it can select anchor points from one currently highlighted path only. So, how can I select this space?

EDIT: Ok, a simple example would be:

Path AB:[image: path AB]

Path CD:[image: path CD]

Final selection (more or less like this):[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the Polygonal Lasso to make a selection (like I assume you did for your sample image).

Either that or connect the two paths to make a shape, then convert the shape to a selection.

Independent paths simply don't work in a way which would allow you to select something between them with some automated method.

Comment: Lasso was ok here, but in a case where there are tens of paths, it's not so nice. Could you elaborate on how to connect paths into shape?

Answer (score 1):

You have to merge the two paths to make a selection.

1. Duplicate *Path 1* (drag & drop to the `Create New Path` button; this will be *Path 3*).
2. Next, select *Path 2* and copy & paste it to *Path 3*.
3. Now, you will have each in one path. If you look at the thumbnail of the path, you will see in white, which area will be selected.
4. After you copied them to a single path, you have to join the two lines with the Pen tool.
5. Now right click on the path, and `Make Selection` ( or  hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> and click on the thumbnail).